# Postgresql - get relation name from relid or RelOptInfo data structure

Tags: postgresql

I want to get the relation name for a given relid or RelOptInfo data structure.

For some experiment I need to fetch the relation name while processing a given query inside postgresql. is there some way of doing this?

Comment: Isn't that what [`pg_class`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/catalog-pg-class.html) is for?

Comment: I want to be able to do that from inside the postgres code, when I am in middle of executing a query, somewhere in parser or in the planner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `RelationGetRelationName(Relation)`.

If you don't have a `Relation`, use `get_rel_name(Oid)`. This uses the syscache so you must have an open transaction. Beware though, it doesn't schema-qualify the name. If you need that, you should probably do a syscache lookup yourself (see the code for `get_rel_name` in `src/backend/utils/cache/lsyscache.c`) so you can also `get_namespace_name` the schema name. Then use `quote_qualified_identifier`.

I am constantly surprised that Pg doesn't seem to have a public C-level equivalent of the `regclass` formatting in `regclassout`. See `src/backend/utils/adt/regproc.c`.

There's `generate_qualified_relation_name`, but it's `static` for some reason. I think I'll submit a patch proposing to move it, `generate_relation_name`  and `get_relation_name` to `lsyscache.c` and make them public.

In the mean time I suggest shameless ripping off what `generate_relation_name` or `generate_qualified_relation_name` does if you're doing something where `get_rel_name` isn't good enough.

**Update**: [patch submitted](https://www.postgresql.org/search/?m=1&q=CAMsr%2BYFJYGvFEP_E38i7jCAN%3DtcFZ40D2yonDLrP%2BJTPu4rH7Q%40mail.gmail.com). Feel free to shamelessly rip off that function.

Comment: I didn't get what do you mean by 'schema-qualify the name' ?

Comment: @GouravKumar `public.mytable` vs just `mytable`. Imagine if there are two `mytable`s, one in schema `public` and one in schema `other`...

Comment: Just like global and local variables with same name. I used get_rel_name(oid), it doesn't gives me relation name but a number. I am not  sure what that number is.

Comment: Er ... what? `get_rel_name` returns a relation name as a string.

Comment: Sorry ! mybad. I used %d instead of %s.  There are some relations though for which I get Oid as 0, and relname as null, in the same query. I am using TPC-DS query 50.

Comment: Some relations are defined in the query using with keyword for those the Oid itself is zero. Any Idea how can I get their name ?

Comment: @GouravKumar Example? Specifics? Please post a *new* more detailed question. Paste a link here.

Comment: Here is the link to new question https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/187831/postgresql-get-oid-and-relation-name-for-relations-created-by-the-query